# Insert values on matching rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here's the script I'm using to find all the matching rows from `mSheet` with the values of `searchText` and insert `value1` in all the matching rows in column(B) and that is working really good.
So what I'm trying to do is also insert the `value` from `value2` on the same matching rows in column(M) I've tried different ways but just can't seem to get it right.

```
function  insert(){
  var mSheet =  SpreadsheetApp.openById('1rAQ0t--PPK0-wovqdc')
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var searchText = ss.getRange('A1').getValue()
  var value1 = ss.getRange('B1').getValue()
  var value2 = ss.getRange('C1').getValue()
  var sheet = mSheet.getSheetByName('Data');
  
  if(searchText!=''){
  var rangeList = sheet
    .getRange('C1:C')
    .createTextFinder(searchText)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findAll()
    .map((r) => r.offset(0, -1).getA1Notation());
    sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).setValue(value1);
    console.log(searchText,value1,rangeList);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Friendly suggestion, since you're doing multiple things on essentially same line of code, be more strict with your `;` usage (see your varaible declarations) that inconsistently use them. Again, not wrong, just some snobby feedback. good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution might be more obvious for you if you broke out some of your lines of code. What you have works fine, but as you can see, you've already essentially done the hard work, you just need to repeat part of it for column `M` (offset 10 columns away). See this to replace your if statement...

```
  if(searchText!=''){
  var rangeList = sheet
    .getRange('C1:C')
    .createTextFinder(searchText)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findAll();
    //Creates two range lists.
    var list1 = rangeList.map(r => r.offset(0, -1).getA1Notation());
    var list2 = rangeList.map(r => r.offset(0, 10).getA1Notation());
    sheet.getRangeList(list1).setValue(value1);
    sheet.getRangeList(list2).setValue(value2);
    console.log(searchText,value1,rangeList);
    }
```

Comment: Honest question here from a novice: wouldn't it take longer to do the offset and getA1Notation again than string manipulation as I proposed? Thinking in a big amount of data, but maybe it's insignificant that's why I'm asking! Thanks

Comment: @Martín, i'm guessing yours is more efficient, but I'm not sure how much since the variable `rangeList` is already established. I was just posting an illustration for OP to show that all the components were there. If performance was my top priority, i'd use the array.filter approach rather than using the find within the range.

Comment: Yes, I understood earlier you were pointing out that, and it's very valuable! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Both solution worked great I've used pgSystemTester solution for my project it was a bit faster on larger data  set Thanks

Comment: @YvanL thanks. Of course.... you could still give Martin an uptick. =)

Answer (score 2):

You could just modify the substring "B" with "M":

```
  var rangeList2 = rangeList.map((n) => n.replace('B','M'))
```

and then:

```
sheet.getRangeList(rangeList2).setValue(value2);
```